# How to show table result column and show it on rows

Tags: php, tabular

[image]

Can someone help me create a table in where I can use the other rows as columns?

My sample database looks like this:

```
|    NAME | DATE             |    TIME     |TYPE |
|    john    | 03-05-2017  |    06:00    | AM IN
|    john    | 03-05-2017  |    11:00    | AM OUT
|    john    | 03-05-2017  |    13:00    | PM IN
|    john    | 03-05-2017  |    16:00    | PM OUT

| john | 03-06-2017  | 06:00 | AM IN
| john | 03-06-2017  | 11:00 | AM OUT

| john | 03-07-2017  | 06:00 | AM IN
| john | 03-07-2017  | 11:00 | AM OUT
| john | 03-07-2017  | 13:00 | PM IN
| john | 03-07-2017  | 16:00 | PM OUT
```

How can I show it like this in PHP table:

```
|    DATE      | AM IN  |AM OUT   |    PM IN    | PMOUT
03-05-2017   06:00     |11:00        |   13:00      |16:00
03-06-2017   06:00     |11:00        |   NULL       | NULL
03-07-2017   06:00    |11:00         |    13:00      |16:00
```

I have uploaded the image so that I can explain it better

Comment: Do you want to create an HTML table, an excel sheet or what kind of table do you mind? What have you tried yet? Please provide an example.

Comment: just a normal html table fetch from that database sir, the example looks like the right part of image uploaded , Thank you so much!\

Comment: Are you looking for an sql query to produce desired result?

Comment: We're glad to help with specific problems, but by know we can't tell what your specific problem is. What have you tried yet to accomplish what you want to do? Do you have problems with the query, with the rendering of the table or with the grouping of the data? A little hint: Please read the [how to as page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what a good question on stackoverflow is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    DATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'AM IN'  THEN TIME END) AS AM_IN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'AM OUT' THEN TIME END) AS AM_OUT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PM IN'  THEN TIME END) AS PM_IN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PM OUT' THEN TIME END) AS PM_OUT
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    NAME, DATE;
```